# Reading a CSV file and plotting graph using Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I would like to create a script in Matlab that can read data from a CSV file and plot it. My data looks something like:

Time    BPM(HeartRate)
5:55:26      0
5:55:26      0
5:55:27      66
5:55:27      70
5:55:27      71
5:55:27      74
...

I would like to plot time on the x axis and BPM on the y axis. I have tried the following:

```
clear, clc;
ftoread = 'data.csv';
fid = fopen(ftoread);

y=data(:,1);
x=data(:,2);
plot(x,y);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Heart Rate');
title('Heart Rate Vs. Time');
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error at `y=data(:,1)`.

Comment: Where do you read in the file? Where does `data` come from?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) instead?

```
data = csvread('data.csv');
x=data(:,1);
y=data(:,2);
% etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing some steps. `csvread` or `dlmread` may not work well since you have a string and a number on each line. [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) should be fast and easy:

```
ftoread = 'data.csv';
fid = fopen(ftoread);
data = textscan(fid,'%s%f'); % Read in a string and a double
fclose(fid); % If you call fopen, make sure you also call fclose

x = data{1};
y = data{2};
```

You'll then may want to use functions like [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) and [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to convert your time strings to other values. I believe that the even accept cell array (like `x`) as inputs.